# Which version of StealJS does CanJS 2.2.7 use?

Tags: canjs, stealjs

I tried using the latest CanJS (2.2.7) and the latest StealJS (I think it is 0.10) but it seems there are some functions is missing, for example:

CanJS uses steal.config() whereas StealJS steal.config function seems does not take undefined parameter.

The documentation is very minimal and I couldn't find any answer there. Is the latest version of StealJS is incompatible with CanJS?

Comment: Take a look at donejs http://donejs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Where does it use steal.config()?

Comment: inside can/view/view define